# Node, spawn multiple dependent shell commands

Tags: node.js, django, gulp

I'm trying to use gulp to activate a virtualenv for python and launch a django server.
Although I can launch the server correctly I can't activate the virtualenv beforehand.  (this breaks integration with my IDE's gulp tool).
Is there a way to make the virtualenv spawn launch first and be part of the child process that launches the server (as the server depends on being in the virtual environment).

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('runServer', function(cb) {
  var virtualenv = spawn('source venv/bin/activate')
  var cmd = spawn('python', ['manage.py', 'runserver'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
  cmd.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('runServer exited with code ' + code);
    cb(code);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
child_process.spawn('venv/bin/python', ['manage.py', 'runserver']);
```

This uses the python env but only requires one command to be executed

Comment: Superb that works thanks.  I'm not 100% sure how - I thought I would need the source in there first. (and why do we use the -i flag?). Thanks

Comment: -i and -u flags might not be necessary here

Comment: Yup definitely don't need -i and testing without -u aswell still seems to pass along the output from the django server to node correctly.

Comment: Reason this works (and don't need any `source` command) is that the usual `source venv/bin/activate` essentially just makes it so when you run the command `python`, it points to the python executable that lives at your `venv/bin/python`. So it follows that you can achieve the same thing by directly pointing to `venv/bin/python` yourself, as this answer does.